# How to put a link inside input box after ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a input box which contain information loaded after ajax success but how to put a modal link target for the text inside input box after ajax success? So after user click the text inside input box, Modal will open. The example as below.

[image]

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label class="form-control-label">NE Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input id="viewEgressNeName" type="text" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url : api_url,
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: id,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: true,
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(response){
        if (response.result == "success"){
            $("#viewEgressNeName").val(response.egress[0]["ne_name"]).attr("readonly", true);
        }
        else {}
    },
    error: function(e){}
});
```

Comment: This is an `input` field of type `text`, so you can't just create a link and embed that inside of it. You could, however, create an event handler that listens for clicks on the `input` field after your `AJAX` call succeeds.

Comment: can you give the example code at the answer so i can imagine how its happen. :-)

Comment: Please put here your ajax response

Comment: currently I don't have the response since waiting the API readiness. I just code for the Front end. However, the output will be like as image above.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're trying to do. Is the input box in a form that gets submitted which then displays a modal after the submission succeeds?

Comment: No, the input box I use to display an info after ajax succeed, not to let user to key-in anything. Actually I used `disabled` attribute, but I removed it during posting above.

Comment: @mastersuse is the modal is bootrsap modal ? or some other ?

Comment: Yes bootstrap 4 modal

Comment: use on click event and show your modal i.e :`$(document).on("click", "#viewEgressNeName", function() {
   $('#yourmodalid').modal('toggle');
});`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, btw I find another solution.